Retrieve information from different databases in Symfony
Hello everyone I'm under a project in Symfony 6.4 where I need to manipulate two database
I have configure my doctrine.yaml file to have 2 entity manager. And have the link to my 2 database (we can consider the names db1 and db2) in my .env file.
#doctrine.yaml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        connections:
            default:
                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
            comptages:
                url: '%env(resolve:COMPTAGE_DATABASE_URL)%'
        default_connection: default

        # IMPORTANT: You MUST configure your server version,
        # either here or in the DATABASE_URL env var (see .env file)
        #server_version: '15'



    orm:
        default_entity_manager: default
        entity_managers:
            default:
                connection: default
                report_fields_where_declared: true
                validate_xml_mapping: true
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
                auto_mapping: true
                mappings:
                    App:
                        is_bundle: false
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity'
                        alias: App
                filters:
                    softdeleteable:
                        class: Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Filter\SoftDeleteableFilter
                        enabled: true
            custom:
                connection: comptages
                mappings:   
                    Comptages:
                        is_bundle: false
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/EntityComptages'
                        prefix: 'App\EntityComptages'
                        alias: Comptages
                filters:
                    softdeleteable:
                        class: Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Filter\SoftDeleteableFilter
                        enabled: true

And I just want to retrieve data from one of my entities from my second database but when executing the following code :
#Controller.php
$entityManager = $doctrine->getManager('custom');
$etat = $entityManager->getRepository(ComptageEtats::class)->find($id);

I get the error :

An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'db1.comptageEtats' doesn't exist

But I don't understand why the request is searching in my db1 instaed of my db2 considering the entitymanager parameters. Maybe a problemm of configuration somewhere ? Or in my repository file ?
Does anyone have manage multiple databases and has faced this problem ?
Maybe it is a problem of migration ? Thanks in advance.

Are you using the standard base ServiceEntityRepository? The is a common problem when you try to manage the same entity type with multiple repositories. But you seems to have different entity namespaces so that should not be the problem. You have no cross referencing between the two set of entities?

Yes I'm using this to define my repository : class ComptageEtatsRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository. I have no referencing between the two sets of entties. I managed the problem by defining the second entity manager in my repository but I'm sure that's a viable solution if I have a lot of repositories to manage.

Not sure what to suggest. As long as the entities are completely independent (as your config suggests) then there should be no problem using two entity managers.  I'm assuming the tables have been created and the code posted is where the error message comes from.
